# Syntax error on declaring a variable inside a transaction

Tags: postgresql, transaction

I want to create a variable inside this transaction but I'm getting

> `ERROR: syntax error at or near "DECLARE" LINE 4: DECLARE new_id INTEGER;`.

The variable needs to hold the value of the `id` of the newly created message.
This seems to be the cleanest and race condition resistant way of doing so, but I don't know how to correctly declare the variable.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

DECLARE new_id INTEGER;
INSERT INTO messages (author) VALUES ($author) RETURNING id INTO new_id;
-- Other statements..

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a declare block before the main block:

```
DECLARE
  -- declarations go here
BEGIN
  -- commands go here
END;
```

If you need this as an anonymous block (not in any function, etc.) also read about [`DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot declare a variable in plain SQL like this. See:

- [User defined variables in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261035/user-defined-variables-in-postgresql/14261927#14261927)

There is a [`DECLARE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-declare.html) command, but it's for cursors - a completely different feature.

You seem to be confusing this with [plpgsql code](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) where each block can have a leading `DECLARE` section, but `BEGIN TRANSACTION` or `COMMIT` are not possible inside plpgsql.

So it's not entirely clear what you are trying to do here.